# Submanifold of Orientable Manifold with Codimension 0 is Orientable

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I'm trying to solve Exercise 15.12 from Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* which says "Suppose M is an oriented smooth manifold with or without boundary, and $D\subset M$ is a smooth codimension-$0$ submanifold with or without boundary. Then the orientation of M restricts to an orientation of D. "

My initial attempt was just to restrict the orientable charts of M to N, and that seemed to work but I don't see why we need the codimension to be $0$. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: My version asks about orientation forms; the pushforward of the differential of the orientation form from the ambient manifold will be non-vanishing because it's an injection.  That's why the codimension matters.  I assume that's what you mean when you say it's a 'local problem.'  Yes, but you have to be very careful about 'local arguments' and orientability/integrability.  I always had problems with it haha

Comment: If the codimension is $\ge 1$ you might have cases such as a Möbius strip embedded in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: For nonzero codimension, the relationship between charts of the ambient manifold and charts of the submanifold are more complicated than just restrictions.

Comment: You have to tell us what does restricting the chart to N mean when the codimension is not zero.